# How to limit height of plotlines in highchart graphs?

Tags: reactjs, graph, react-chartjs, react-highcharts, react-chartjs-2

by default the plotlines are infinite but i want to restrict the height of plotlines
how can i achieve that without using below code
[image: this is for normal js but i want the code for ReactJS]

I want solution in ReactJS.
please help me with this if possible
thanks ✌️

I have tried searching documentation but couldn't find any existing solution.